# Header reapting itself in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have ONE a header above all the other stuff, but it just get repeated. I tried to but the header div above the section also but it just errored.

```
import React from "react";
export const Album = (props) => {
    return (
        <section className="musicList">
            <div clasName="header">New albums and singles</div>
            <div className="card">
                <div className="images">
                    <a className="album-link" href={props.albumUrl} target="_blank"><img className="image" src={props.image} /></a>
                    <div className="middle">
                        <div className="icons">
                            <img src="icons/heart.svg" className="heart"></img>
                            <img src="icons/play.svg" className="play"></img>
                            <img src="icons/dots.svg" className="dots"></img>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>


                <div className="song">
                    {props.song}
                </div>

                <div className="artist">
                    {props.artist.map((artists) => {
                        return <span key={artists.id}><a className="artist-link" href={artists.external_urls.spotify} target="_blank">{artists.name}</a><span>,&nbsp;</span></span>

                    })}
                </div>

            </div>

        </section>
    )
};
```

Comment: are you using react router?

Comment: What error did you get? It helps to include the exact text so we can advise.

Comment: ./src/Album.js
  Line 5:9:  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

  3 |     return (
  4 |         <div clasName="header">New albums and singles</div>
> 5 |         <section className="musicList">
    |         ^
  6 |         
  7 |             <div className="card">
  8 |                 <div className="images">

Comment: You've put the title in the repeated _item_ component named `Album`. Move the title in the parent component, outside of the loop and voilà!

Comment: Thank you! It helped!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here:

```
<div clasName="header">New albums and singles</div>
```

It should be called `className` instead of `clasName`.

Comment: Oh thank you. changed that now but it still repeats itself though